# Failure to start system from EFI shell

Tags: linux-mint, boot, uefi, manjaro

While attempting to install Mint 21.2/Manjaro 23.0.1 on Irbis TW60 [(system specs)](https://e-catalog.com/ek-item.php?resolved_name_=IRBIS-TW60&view_=tbl) I was dropped into an EFI shell. Booting from it is not possible, as outlined below.

**What is known:**

- Secure Boot is off;
- EFI Shell is at version 2.1;
- Installer USB is on `FS0`;
- EFI file is located at `FS0:\efi\boot\grubx64.efi`.

**What is supposed to happen:** Upon execution of any .efi file I should be thrown either into GRUB or memory check.

**What actually happens:** Nothing.

EFI shell output:

```
Shell> FS0:
FS0:> cd efi\boot
FS0:\efi\boot> dir
Directory of: FS0:\efi\boot\
04/15/2022 22:08 <DIR>      2.048 .
04/15/2022 22:08 <DIR>          0 ..
04/15/2022 22:08         $size_x  mmx64.efi
04/15/2022 22:08         $size_y  grubx64.efi
04/15/2022 22:08         $size_z  bootx64.efi
    3 File(s) $total_size bytes
    2 Dir(s)
FS0:\efi\boot> grubx64.efi
FS0:\efi\boot>
```

Comment: Maybe it uses a 32-bit version of UEFI for some reason?

Comment: @telcoM will try it out, guessing this is not unheard of?

Comment: (1) Did you test your USB installation media at an other system *[Legacy boot must be disabled!]*? (2) How did you create the USB installation media? (3) Please update your question by providing the output of `lsblk -o path,mountpoint,partflags,parttype,size,fstype,uuid`

Comment: (1) No, I did not. (2) Using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) in both DD and ISO mode. (3) Seems irrelevant, as media was created on Windows. @dodrg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing various other distros I was able to launch a Debian ISO, and the installer on it. It failed at the "Installing the system" stage, installing manually via `debootstrap` however went well.

After `chroot`ing I installed the `grub-efi-ia32` package and installed `grub` as follows:

```
grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=$NAME --target=i386-efi
update-grub
```

The device now works properly.

**Lessons learned:**

- Not every 64-bit system uses a 64 bit bootloader.